# Numbering rows without window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.2

In Postgresql 8.2 I want to sequentially number rows. I have the table `t` at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!10/f1f0d/1):

```
    c 
   ---
    3
    2
```

I want this:

```
    c | i 
   ---+---
    2 | 1
    3 | 2
```

I tried this:

```
select *
from
    (select c from t order by c) s
    cross join
    generate_series(1, 2) i
```

And got:

```
    c | i 
   ---+---
    2 | 1
    3 | 1
    2 | 2
    3 | 2
```

Comment: 8.2 is long de-supported. You should upgrade ***now***

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The client just want a quick fix for a single problem. Not much opportunity to evangelize.

Comment: The client should still consider upgrading *very* soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is a sequence. You could do something like this:

```
drop sequence if exists row_numbers;
create temporary sequence row_numbers;

select next_val('row_numbers'), dt.c
from (select c from t order by c) as dt;
```

I'd throw a `drop sequence row_numbers` in as well but the `temporary` should take care of that if you forget.

This is a bit cumbersome but you might be able to wrap it in a function to hide some of the ugliness.

Keep in mind that 8.2 is no longer supported but 8.4 is and 8.4 has window functions.

---

References (8.2 versions):

- [CREATE SEQUENCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createsequence.html)
- [DROP SEQUENCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-dropsequence.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a "triangular join" as in the following:

```
select a.c, (select count(*) from t where c <= a.c) as i
from t as a
order by i
```

This assumes, however, that the values of `c` are unique, as the "row numbering" scheme is simply a count of rows that are less-than-or-equal to the current row.  This can be expanded to included a primary key or other unique column for tie-breaking, as necessary.

Also, there can be some [performance implications](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/) with joining in this manner.

Comment: +1 `c` is not unique and I could use a second row which is. Performance is not a problem as it is a one time operation. But I preferred the sequence solution as that is what I was planning before posting and I already had it all in my mind (It is much more complex than my example).